# How to prevent teeth from move outside jaw when bone is moved

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

As you can see in the picture below, whenever I move the jaw bone, part of the teeth appear on the outside. What's the best way to fix this issue?
[image]

Comment: maybe change their shape?

Comment: You may want to work on the weighting (Weight Paint) of the teeth and the mouth vertices when the appropriate (problem) bone is selected.

Comment: Probably, by weighting the teeth the same as the jaw.  But there are tons of potential details that could affect the answer, and we couldn't answer with any kind of certainty without seeing the file.

Answer (score 1):

I will show by example how adjusting the vertex weights (for a given bone) can help prevent this sort of undesirable effect.  This may or may not help in your case, and there may be other solutions.

In [image], I created two meshes, the sphere to represent the face/lips and a cube to represent the teeth, and an armature of a couple of 4 bones where the final bone (Bone.003) will be moved to demonstrate.

I duplicated these so I have before and after edit groups.  As you'll see when I put the cube into Weight Paint mode and select the Bone.003 Vertex Group:

[image: select vertex group]

, the weighting is red (heavy weighting) near the bone and bluer (light weighting) further away.

[image: original weighting]

I then Paint the weightings around the vertices I want to have heavier weighting (teeth closets to the lips):

[image: weight painted]

Now when I move the Bone.003 in each copy of my Armature groupings, you'll see that in one the cube shows through the sphere and in the other it doesn't:

[image: results]

Now your problem may be the opposite: you may want to more heavily or lightly weight the lip area of the character for the jaw-bone vertex group.